# yum error and configuration for redhat

Tags: rhel, yum

I followed the instructions but it did not work

```
[root@Ready4Use ~]# yum clean metadata
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Network error code: 400
Cleaning repos: rhel-7-server-rpms rhel-7-server-rt-beta-rpms rhel-7-server-rt-rpms
0 metadata files removed
0 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed
[root@Ready4Use ~]# yum install rsync
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Network error code: 400
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.

I am trying to install rsync on my redhat box
i tried  

    yum install rsync but i get 
    [root@Ready4Use yum.repos.d]# yum install rsync
    Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
    Network error code: 400
    https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
    Trying other mirror


I checked in the redhat.repo file and there are tons of urls for different repositories 

example:

    [root@Ready4Use yum.repos.d]# grep baseurl redhat.repo
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/dotnet/1/debug
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/sat-tools/6.2/os
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/v2vwin/debug
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/insights/3/debug
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/sap/source/SRPMS
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/server/7/$basearch/resilientstorage/debug
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/resilientstorage/source/SRPMS
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/openstack-tools/11/debug
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/x86_64/cdk/2.3/os
    baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/rhscl/1/source/SRPMS
```

My repolist:

```
[root@Ready4Use yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Network error code: 400
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/server/7/x86_64/rt/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/rt/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
repo id                                                                      repo name                                                                                                   status
rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)                                                                    0
rhel-7-server-rt-beta-rpms/x86_64                                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Real Time Beta (RHEL 7 Server) (RPMs)                                          0
rhel-7-server-rt-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Real Time (RHEL 7 Server) (RPMs)                                               0
repolist: 0
[root@Ready4Use yum.repos.d]#
```

i tried manually going to the url and i do indeed get the same error.
Is there some item I need to configure in yum?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `subscription-manager status` show that you are registered?

Comment: to be honest i do not think we are.  this is my test VM.  On the other hand i was able to install the sync package via centos

Answer (score -1):

```
yum clean metadata
yum install rsync
```

Comment: This won’t work unless you add a subscription, which the post clearly shows is missing.